# How does the React component's state changes by using [event.target.name]?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an update form to update the user's info.

```
 const { basic: userBasic } = this.state.user; 

 <Modal open={openEditBasicModal} size="small">
      <Modal.Header>Your basic details</Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Content scrolling>
        <Form>
          <Form.Group inline widths="equal">
            <Form.Input
              fluid
              type="text"
              name="firstName"
              defaultValue={userBasic.firstName}
              onChange={this.handleBasicFromInputValue}
              label="First Name"
            />
            <Form.Input
              fluid
              type="text"
              name="lastName"
              defaultValue={userBasic.lastName}
              onChange={this.handleBasicFromInputValue}
              label="Last Name"
            />
          </Form.Group>             
        </Form>
      </Modal.Content>
      <Modal.Actions open={true}>
        <Button
          primary
          onClick={this.updateUserBasicInfo}>
          Update
        </Button>
      </Modal.Actions>
    </Modal>
```

The component's state is:

```
this.state = {
      user: {
        basic: {
          firstName: null,
          lastName: null,
          email: null
        },
        //others
      }
}
```

The default value in the form is from the `state` and the logic is to update the `state` by using `onChange` handler on the forms fields. So I used the one simple handler for this:

```
handleBasicFromInputValue = event => {
    this.setState({
      user: {
        basic: {
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

The above handler **DID** update the state, **BUT** it also remove the `state` schema declared in the component. If the user state was having

```
user: {
    basic: {
      firstName: "theCoder",
      lastName: "lastCoder",
      email: "something@gmail"
    }
}
```

and now I update the `firstName` field in the form, the state gets changed to

```
user: {
    basic: {
      firstName: "theCoderUpdated",
    }
}
```

If I print the user state now on form submit:

```
  updateUserBasicInfo = () => {
    console.log(this.state.user.basic);
  }
```

It only prints object containg `firstName: "theCoderUpdated"`

All other state variables have vanished. Shouldn't the other state variables remain unchanged?
I think this is the `[event.target.name]` which is causing the issue, but I am not sure why.

How does the `[event.target.name]` works behind the scene? And what would be the right way to do this state change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React only does shallow state merging. You can read about it here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged

That means that all when you call `setState`, all the top level properties are replaced completetly. For you, that means that `user` is completely replaced with the new user-object that you send in with `setState`. You can solve this in two ways. Either you flatten your state object, and have `firstName`, `lastName`, `email` in your state like this:

```
this.state = {
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,
  email: null
}
```

or you have to update your state like this:

```
handleBasicFromInputValue = event => {
    this.setState({
      user: {
        basic: {
          ...this.state.user.basic,
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing the basic object. Do it like this to keep the previous props

```
const shallowCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state.user);
shallowCopy.basic[event.target.name] = event.target.value
this.setState({user : shallowCopy});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is when you create the new state that you don't maintain the old values.

Try this:

```
    handleBasicFromInputValue = event => {
      const { user } = this.state;        
      this.setState({
          user: {
            ...user,
            basic: {
              ...user.basic,
              [event.target.name]: event.target.value
            }
          }
        });
      };
```

When you do "setState" you are creating a **new state** so that's when **you change what you want but you must also maintain what you already had**.

You can see that in [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged)

With [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) you are making a copy of what you already had and you add what you want to change.

PS: what you want to change always behind what you already had because otherwise it is possible to replace it since you are making a copy of what was before.

I hope I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the basic object. you can do it like .

this.state.user.basic[event.target.name] =event.target.value;
this.setState({user : this.state.user});

Comment: It is a bad practice to directly work on an immutable state. What's the whole point of setState() here?

Answer (score 0):

You replace the state with the new one when assigning the firstName, as you are going beyond shallow copy. You have to do it like this:

```
handleBasicFromInputValue = (event) => {
   var temp = this.state.user;
   temp.basic[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
   this.setState({
      user: temp
   });
 };
```